# TypeError: navList.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, nav

it says TypeError: navList.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function i don't seem to identify the problem,
the idea is to create a dynamic navigation bar based on how many sections are there
and the button does not work too
it suppose to create a new section when it is pressed
if anybody knows what i'm doing wrong please inform me
note: the js is not done yet i havent built the intersection observer yet

```js
/**
 * 
 * Manipulating the DOM exercise.
 * Exercise programmatically builds navigation,
 * scrolls to anchors from navigation,
 * and highlights section in viewport upon scrolling.
 * 
 * Dependencies: None
 * 
 * JS Version: ES2015/ES6
 * 
 * JS Standard: ESlint
 * 
*/

/**
 * Comments should be present at the beginning of each procedure and class.
 * Great to have comments before crucial code sections within the procedure.
*/

/**
 * Define Global Variables
 * 
*/
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
let navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const buildSecBtn = document.getElementById("newSection");
const main = document.querySelector("main");

/**
 * End Global Variables
 * Start Helper Functions
 * 
*/
const counter = 0;
const buildSection = () => {
    counter++
    const newSec =  ` <section id="section${counter}" data-nav="Section ${counter}" class="">
        <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section ${counter}</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>
        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
        </div>
        </section>`
    main.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newSec);
};


/**
 * End Helper Functions
 * Begin Main Functions
 * 
*/

// build the nav
const buildNav = () => {
    sections.forEach(section => {
        navList = "";
        const navItem = `<li><a class="menu__link" data-nav="${section.id}" href="${seciton.id}"></a>${section.dataset.nav}</li>`
        navList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", navItem);
    })
}
buildNav();
// Add class 'active' to section when near top of viewport


// Scroll to anchor ID using scrollTO event


/**
 * End Main Functions
 * Begin Events
 * 
*/

// Build menu 
buildSecBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    buildSection();
    console.log(counter)
})
// Scroll to section on link click

// Set sections as active
```

```css
/*
 *
 * CSS written based on SMACSS architecture.
 * To learn more, visit: http://smacss.com/
 * 
 * For simplicity, no reset or normalize is added. 
 * To learn more, visit: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/
 *
*/


/* ---- Base Rules ---- */
body {
    background: rgb(136,203,171);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(136,203,171,1) 0%, rgba(0,13,60,1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Typeography General*/
h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 2em 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    h1 {
        font-size: 7em;
        margin: 2em 4rem 1em;
    }
}

h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: #eee;
}

/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */
main {
    margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}

.main-hero {
    min-height: 40vh;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80vh;
}


/* ---- Module Rules ---- */

/* Navigation Styles*/
.navbar__menu ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.navbar__menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    transition: ease 0.3s all;
}

/* Header Styles */
.page__header {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

/* Footer Styles */
.page__footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}

.page__footer p{
    color: #fff;
}


/* ---- Theme Rules ---- */
/* Landing Container Styles */
.landing__container {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    .landing__container {
        max-width: 50em;
        padding: 4em;
    }
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right; 
}

/* Background Circles */
/* Note that background circles are created with psuedo elements before and after */
/* Circles appear to be random do to use of :nth-of-type psuedo class */
section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20vw;
    bottom: -5em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 15vh;
    height: 15vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}


/* ---- Theme State Rules ---- */
/* Section Active Styles */
/* Note: your-active-class class is applied through javascript. You should update the class here and in the index.html to what you set in your javascript file.  */
section.your-active-class {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::before {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::after {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}

/* Section Active Styles Keyframe Animations */
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-1em)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-1em) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <button id="newSection"> add section </button>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
    a data attribute that will populate the li node.
    Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
    The first section is set to active class by default -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I bet the error is actually saying "seciton is not defined" because you have a typo in the code.

Comment: Wow, @Andy, good eye!

Comment: @Andy wow, there is a new error TypeError: navList.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function

Comment: Move the script call to just before `</body>`. You need to ensure the DOM loads first before you can access the elements with the JS.